# Parenting Mesh to Armature: Value not found?

Tags: mesh, armature, parent

[image]
I made an armature and added the deform with weight and I have a merged mesh and completed armature.
However, the armature doesn't make the mesh move.
I try setting the mesh's parent to the armature in object properties but I get a small error message saying the value isn't found.

Comment: Also note, I believe this may be due to having the body mesh as the same object as the armature but I don't know how to separate them?

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: You are in *Pose* mode and have selected the *root* bone. This bone has no parent because and it makes no sense to assign a parent to it because it's the root ;-) If you want to parent the mesh and the armature you need to be in *Object* mode. Select both and make sure you select them in the correct order (that is: armature last=yellowish selection color; mesh selected first=reddish), then parent them *With Automatic Weights* (key P).